# TSQL: getting next available ID

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Using SQL Server 2008, have three tables, table a, table b and table c.

All have an `ID` column, but for table a and b the `ID` column is an `identity integer`, for table c the `ID` column is a `varchar` type

Currently a stored procedure take a name param, following certain logic, insert to table a or table b, get the identity, prefix with 'A' or 'B' then insert to table c.

Problem is, table C `ID` column potentially have the duplicated values, i.e. if identity from table A is 2, there might already have 'A2','A3','A5' in the `ID` column for table C, how to write a T-SQL query to identify the next available value in table C then ensure to update table A/B accordingly?

[Update]
this is the current step,
1. depends on input parameter, insert to table A or table B 
2. initialize seed value =  @@Identity
3. calculate ID value to insert to table C by prefix 'A' or append 'B' with the seed value 
4. look for record match in table C by ID value from step 3, if didn't find any record, insert it, else increase seed value by 1 then repeat step 3

The issue being at a certain value range, there could be a huge block of value exists in table C ID, i.e. A3000 to A500000 existed now in table C ID, the database query is extemely slow if follow the existing logic. Needs to figure out a logic to smartly get the minimum available number (without the prefix)

it is hard to describe, hope this make more sense, I truly appreciate any help on this Thanks in advance!

Comment: You would be much better off redesigning this.  It is really not a good approach

Comment: If the `ID` in tables A and B is really `INT IDENTITY` - how could it ever give you duplicates? Seems impossible to me, if you're using the table prefix (A or B) plus the **unique** value of the `ID` column in tables A or B in your table C ....

Comment: @Tommy Wang, can you edit your post and give us a more detailed example?

Comment: @Tommy Wang, are you trying to prevent the key ID column of A from having any of the same values as the key ID column of B? If so, have you considered using GUIDs as primary keys instead of integers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick.  Simple self extracting example will work in SSMS.  I even made it out of order just in case.  You would just change your table to be where @Data is and then change Identifier field to replace 'ID'.

```
declare @Data Table ( Id varchar(3) );

insert into @Data values ('A5'),('A2'),('B1'),('A3'),('B2'),('A4'),('A1'),('A6');

With a as 
    (
    Select
        ID
    ,   cast(right(Id, len(Id)-1)  as int) as Pos
    ,   left(Id, 1) as TableFrom
    from @Data
    )
select
    TableFrom
,   max(Pos) + 1 as NextNumberUp
from a
group by TableFrom
```

EDIT:  If you want to not worry about production data you could add this last part amending what I wrote:

```
Select
   TableFrom 
,  max(Pos) as LastPos
into #Temp
from a
group by TableFrom

select TableFrom, LastPos + 1
from #Temp
```

Regardless if this was production environment you are going to have to hit part of it at some time to get data.  If the datasets are not too large and just varchar(256) or less and only 5 million rows or less you could dump that entire column from tableC to a temp table.  Honestly query performance versus imports change vastly from system to system.

Comment: This might work just fine in a one-user test environment - but in a production system under load, with multiple users hitting your database, a  `SELECT MAX() + 1` approach will sooner or later fail miserably and produce duplicate values......

Comment: Fair enough I will update my answer with a temp table for what you state as that could be true.

Comment: +1 for a good answer to an ugly question.  But you are just letting a bad data design live on.

Comment: I would add to that if you are in a production environment you should not really be doing this as the instance I think that Marc_S is hinting at is this: If you get a value at time x, say 11:00 AM.  And users are inserting constantly at time y, say 11:01 AM, my data could already be invalid.  For this reason you need to account that data may become stale or be aware that when the query is ran that data is only good for transactions listed in that scope of time exactly.  The only way to counter this would be to lock the tables out until you were done, but for a simple example my solution works.

Answer (score 1):

Following your design there shouldn't be any duplicates in Table C considering that A and B are unique.

```
A | B | C
1   1   A1
2   2   A2
        B1
        B2
```